# How can I determine the velocity after impact of a 2D ball collision?

Tags: collision-detection, collision-resolution

Consider two balls moving towards each other. Each has a given mass and velocity. Assuming the balls collide, how can you determine what direction the balls will take afterwards? (taking into consideration the mass & velocity)

I realise it's quite a big question, perhaps someone could direct me to an appropriate tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely recommend reading [Pool Hall Lessons: Fast, Accurate Collision Detection Between Circles or Spheres](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3015/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php). It will give you a lot of information about circle to circle collisions, and how to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

This site has a good tutorial just for your question, I like it because it has a lot of ***helpful diagrams*** to help you understand the concept, and gives plenty of example code:

[The Physics of elastic collisions between particles](http://www.director-online.com/buildArticle.php?id=532)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for has already been answered on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling).

Hope that helps.